# Why Use 1024 for a buffer?

Tags: c#, .net

I was going through some source code written by another developer and I came across the following line of code when it comes to streams (file, memory, etc) and file/content uploads. Is there a particular reason that this person is using 1024 as a buffer? Why is this 1024 multiplied by 16?

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
```

Could someone please clarify this further? Also, it would be awesome if anyone can direct me towards articles, etc to further read and understand this.

Comment: Because 'kilo' in computer != 'kilo' in human.

Comment: They could have chose 16*1000 and would not have made a difference in any normal sense

Comment: There is no reason.  You just need a large buffer so you do not get overflow condition.  Typically people make buffer a power of 2.  The reason for 16 is developed imagined that up to 16 messages (with max of 1024) would be seen as a worse case condition.   But this was just a guesstimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1024 is the exact amount of bytes in a kilobyte. All that line means is that they are creating a buffer of 16 KB. That's really all there is to it. If you want to go down the route of why there are 1024 bytes in a kilobyte and why it's a good idea to use that in programming, [this](https://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/why_1024_bytes) would be a good place to start. [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/218236) would also be a good place to look. Although it's talking about disk space, it's the same general idea.

Answer (score 3):

The practice of allocating memory in powers of 2 is holdover from days of yore. Word sizes are powers of 2 (e.g. fullword = 32 bits, doubleword = 8 bits), and virtual memory page sizes were powers of 2. You wanted your allocated memory to align on convenient boundaries as it made execution more efficient. For instance, once upon a time, loading a word or double word into a register was more expensive in terms of CPU cycles if it wasn't on an appropriate boundary (e.g, memory address divisible by 4 or 8 respectively). And if you were allocating a big chunk of memory, you might as well consume a whole page of virtual memory, because you'd likely lock an entire page anyway.

These day it doesn't really matter, but old practices die hard.

[And unless you knew something about how the memory allocator worked and how many words of overhead were involved in each `malloc()`'d block... it probably didn't work anyway.